# Select random drop-down value in Geb

Tags: grails, automated-tests, geb

I want to select a random HTML select option in my test, however the options are generated dynamically and their IDs aren't necessarily clear at the time of running the test.

I am using page objects and content DSL (actually just defining the form as `form { $("form") }` as I had issues otherwise), and I know that I can assign a particular ID or text value to the `form.dropdown` control, but I'm not sure what's the easiest way to obtain a list of all dropdown value IDs (or better yet their mapping to names) for this dropdown.

I've so far tried just to check the type of `form.dropdown` but it is reported as ArrayList and contains null values so that's not very useful.

I've read through the Geb guide but didn't manage to find a good solution in what I believe is the relevant section:

http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/all.html#setting_values

FWIW I'm using Groovy/Grails with Firefox WebRunner.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery like selector for choosing dropdowns?

Comment: Not yet, I thought there may be a native API to do this.

Comment: You can use jquery for selecting. Geb uses similar api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a 'gebish' way to do this, but you can get the values and labels using a selector

```
$('form select[name="dropdown"] option').each {
        println it.text() + ' :: ' + it.value()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I did it. Having this form:

```
<form id="myform">
    <select name="dropdown">
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

First get the options, for simplicity:

```
def options = $('#myform select[name="dropdown"] option')
```

Then, generate a random index this way:

```
int numOptions = options.size()
int randomIndex = System.currentTimeMillis() % numOptions
```

Finally, because I haven't yet found how to set the option by index, I set it by value:

```
String randomValue = options[randomIndex].value()
$('#myform').dropdown = randomValue
```

Or, to make a long story short,

```
def options = $('#myform select[name="dropdown"] option')
$('#myform').dropdown = options[(System.currentTimeMillis() % options.size()) as int].value()
```

We can also reference the SELECT from the OPTION, avoiding unnecessary CSS selections:

```
def options = $('#myform select[name="dropdown"] option')
options.parent().value( options[(System.currentTimeMillis() % options.size()) as int].value() )
```

Hope it works.